# Browser scroll when div expands using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to expand and collapse a div by simply modifying the divs height with each click based on a switch event.

Right now, I'm trying to find a way to get the screen to scroll down to view the div better, so the user doesn't have to scroll down themselves. I'm fairly new to jQuery. Does anyone know how to do such a thing?

Also, comments on how I could improve my code would be appreciated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site_sections.css">

<div id="site_sections_container">

    <div class="site_sections_item" id="blog">

        <div class="site_sections_item_drop_button" id="blogdrop"></div>

        <div class="site_sections_item_title">LATEST BLOG ENTRY</div>

    </div>

    <div class="site_sections_item" id="s">

        <div class="site_sections_item_drop_button" id="sdrop"></div>

        <div class="site_sections_item_title">S</div>

    </div>

</div>

<script>
var switchnum = null;
$( "#blog" ).click(function() {

    if(switchnum == null){
        switchnum = 1;
    }

    if(switchnum == 1){

        $( "#blog" ).css( "height" , "399px" );
        switchnum = 2;

    } else {

        $( "#blog" ).css( "height" , "99px" );
        switchnum = 1;

    }

});

$( "#s" ).click(function() {

    if(switchnum == null){
        switchnum = 1;
    }

    if(switchnum == 1){

        $( "#s" ).css( "height" , "399px" );
        switchnum = 2;

    } else {

        $( "#s" ).css( "height" , "99px" );
        switchnum = 1;

    }

});

</script>
```

While I'm at it, does anyone know how I could link all my jQuery as an external file? I have a `<script>` tag pointing to the jQuery file, but how would I link an external file to a document such as this? I've tried `<script src="js/whatever.js">` and that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code works well as you mentioned.

```
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#blog").offset().top-20 }, 2000);
```

Comment: Woah.. okay. I tried a similar block of code earlier. Can you explain what's going on with the `.animate` onwards? *EDIT* this doesn't seem to be working at all. I implemented it here: `if(switchnum == 1){

        $( "#blog" ).css( "height" , "399px" );
        switchnum = 2;
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#blog").offset().top-20 }, 2000);
 
    }`